# Convert nested CSV data file to JSON

Tags: json, perl, csv

I am trying to create a Perl function which converts CSV with a special format to JSON.

I have a CSV file where every line has the following format

```
child_number,parent_number,status
```

The root parent (without a parent) has `parent_number` = `NA`.

My goal is to convert into JSON format like this

```
{
number:
status:
children: [
    {
        number: 
        status: 
        children: [
            {
                number: 
                status:
            }
        ]
    },
        number: 
        status: 
        children: [
            {
                number: 
                status:
            }
        ]
     ]
}
```

I inserted the contents of the CSV file into an array and found the line with no parent

```perl
foreach my $line ( @csv_arr ) {
    ($child, $perent, $status) = split(/,/,$line);
    last if ( $perent eq "NA" );
}

return 0 unless($perent eq "NA");
```

I would like to get the children for each `$perent` and insert them into the data structure. I could use the following

```perl
push @{ $json_struct->{usage} }, {
    number   => $perent,
    children => getChildren(),
};

...

my @json_arr = JSON::PP->new->encode($json_struct);
```

In order to explain myself better, please consider the following example

```
> cat ./csv_file
7,5,0
5,NA,0
3,5,1
```

```
> cat ./json_file
{
  number: NA
  status: 0
  children: [
      {
          number: 5
          status: 0
          children: [
              {
                  number: 3
                  status: 1
              },
              {
                  number: 7
                  status: 0
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
```

These are the contents of the CSV file after a real run

```
7696,44641,0                                                                                                
44654,44641,0                                                                                              
44646,44641,0                                                                                               
44644,44641,0                                                                                               
44651,44649,0                                                                                               
7700,44641,0
7691,44641,0
44657,44641,0
7699,7698,0
7692,44641,0
44650,44649,0
44661,44660,0
44656,44654,1
44659,44641,0
44648,44646,0
7695,7694,0
44662,44660,0
44641,NA,0
7701,7700,0
7698,44641,0
44653,44651,1
44645,44644,0
44647,44646,0
44649,44641,0
44660,44641,0
7697,7696,0
7689,7688,0
7694,44641,0
44658,44657,1
7693,44641,0
7688,44641,0
```

What is the proper way to implement this method in Perl?

Comment: So there are multiple parents in the file?  Why does `children:` also have `children:` -- are there multiple levels, so that some parents are children of other parents ...?  If so, is there any limit?

Comment: @zdim you can view it as a family tree of process. Each process can have a one or more children. Also , There are process without children. It can be multi level. Each process has only one perent (except root)

Comment: How big is this whole thing? Say, how many lines in a file, roughly how many hierarchy levels?

Comment: Can you provide a (short but consistent) sample of input data? So that everybody is on the same page.

Comment: @zdim Please check out my edit (I added a real-run example). it can be really long.

Comment: @TTaJTa4: Please answer *"how many lines in a file, roughly how many hierarchy levels?"*

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::PP ();

my %nodes;
$nodes{NA} = { number => 'NA', status => 0 };

while (my $line = readline DATA) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($id, $parent_id, $status) = split /,/, $line;
    my $node = $nodes{$id} //= {};
    $node->{number} = 0 + $id;
    $node->{status} = 0 + $status;
    push @{ $nodes{$parent_id}{children} }, $node;
}

my $jsonpp = JSON::PP->new->pretty->canonical;
print $jsonpp->encode($nodes{NA});

__DATA__
7,5,0
5,NA,0
3,5,1
```

Output:

```
{
   "children" : [
      {
         "children" : [
            {
               "number" : 7,
               "status" : 0
            },
            {
               "number" : 3,
               "status" : 1
            }
         ],
         "number" : 5,
         "status" : 0
      }
   ],
   "number" : "NA",
   "status" : 0
}
```

The only reason

```
$nodes{NA} = { number => 'NA', status => 0 };
```

is there is to give the root node a `number` and `status` field. It doesn't otherwise exist in your CSV input, so without that line you'd get a root object containing only a `children` field.

For every CSV record we extract its id, the corresponding parent id, and the status.

If we've already created a node for this id (this happens if another node has already specified this node as its parent), we just use the existing node; otherwise we create a new empty node and store it in `%nodes`.

`%nodes` is our universe of nodes indexed by their id.

We always set the `number` and `status` fields. The `0 +` part is to explicitly convert the values to numbers (otherwise they'd be quoted in the JSON output).

We add our current node to the list of children of its parent (which is found in `$nodes{$parent_id}{children}`).

At the end we simply pretty-print the tree under `$nodes{NA}`, including its children, their children-children, and so on.

Comment: This is excellent. I had considered something similar, but couldn't fathom a way to exclude all of the non-root elements of the hash. But of course the *value* of `$nodes{NA}` node is a reference to the root of the tree that we're interested in, and no other keys of `%nodes` are involved—they were just a tool to build the tree. It's startling that this can be done with just a single hash. Am I now going to be told that this is a known algorithm? What happens if the data represents disconnected data?

Comment: @Borodin I don't know if his algorithm has a name. I came up with it myself for this answer. If there are multiple roots (or nodes above `NA`), they're going to be ignored (we only care about stuff under `NA`). If there are any loops in the graph, we're going to leak memory (and probably get either an exception or an infinite loop in the JSON encoder).

Comment: Yes, the check for self-consistent data, and the existence of a root are missing, but this is a fine basis. I normally reach for [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph), and have written the vestiges of a plugin for it, but I never got as far as looking at how it worked.

Comment: *"I don't know if [t]his algorithm has a name"* I doubt it: it's essentially building a hash tree, with the very neat result that the child of the root contains none of the intermediate data. I may write something that will find any roots (nodes with no parent) in the result, and check for circularity etc. Thank you.